# How to rename a file with different name?

Tags: shell, files, scripting, rename

I have a file named `servername_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls`

I have to create multiple copies of this file, with the condition that server name should be changed in each file created

e.g.

original file-name:

```
servername_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls
```

newly created files names should be like this:

```
servername_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls 
test_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls 
example_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls
```

Comment: What determines the new filenames?

Comment: the tool for the job is larry wall's rename (`apt-get install rename`).

Comment: DOTA@ that did not work.. to be more clear. i have .xls file.. like this servername_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls .... i have to create the same file 100 times with 100 diff server names. so the servername field should be changing for every new file created with the server list i have. ... from the script you have given.. i have created server_list file and inserted server names in it and executed it. rest all i kept same...my OS- redhat. ty

Comment: *"i have created server_list file"*  please [edit] your question to include a minimal sample of this file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/347907/sanjay-golla and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/347925/sanjay-golla. You’ll then be able to [edit] your question.

Comment: Let me also suggest that "rename" is not the verb you want, I think. You want to take one file and create multiple *copies*.

Comment: you are right.. rename is not correct verb. from one file and create multiple copies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how we're deterministically determining servername (I'm just iterating through a space delimited list of servernames in `$server_list`), but here's maybe a skeleton you can work from:

`fn='_test_LINUX_test_test_2019-04-19.xls'; for s in $server_list; do cp -a servername$fn $s$fn; done`